# Backgroundworker Call DLL Send Stop Event

Tags: c#, asynchronous, backgroundworker

I have a Tool which separates the GUI from my Workingengine. They are different Projects. Perhaps I want to use it later for a console application.
I call the Engine (it's a dll) from GUI in a BackgroundWorker:

```
    _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    _worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    _worker.DoWork += DoWork;
    _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    ...


    private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Engine.Engine engine = new Engine.Engine(someParams);
        engine.Log += OnLog; //Here I receive Logging to display in GUI
        engine.Start(); //Runs the logic
    }
```

What i now want is, to implement a stop button. The Engine may run quite a bit and makes transactions in Database (which i want to rollback if stop is clicked).

I could do it by passing the backgroundworker down to my dll and check then for CancellationPending. Is there a different way to do that? I want to reuse the code for other projects, therefor I don't want to pass the Backgroundworker...

What would be nice:

Engine has a stop event, that sets a global flag to "cancel" which I can check periodically in code.
This Event I would like to fire from the GUI.

I hope you can understand what I mean :-)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You'll have to pass a delegate to your engine, one it can use to check if CancellationPending is true.  You may want to take a look at the .NET 4 Task class, cancellation is better integrated in that class.

Comment: Hi Hans! Thanks for your fast reply! Do you have a code snippet for me for passing a delegate to my dll? I tried but didn't work sadly... Thank you very much!